# How can you store an innerHTML that changes into a global variable that can be passed everywhere?

Tags: javascript

How can you store a innerHTML value into a global string that can be used in other functions?

I'm doing the calculator project

For example I use this function to check if a input has a value and add the value to the input. But I want to store this variable globally so it can be used everywhere. How can you do that?

```
var select = document.querySelector('#buttons')
var operating = document.querySelector('#operators')

select.addEventListener('click', selector)
operating.addEventListener('click', operatorSign)

let result;
console.log(result)

function selector(event) {
  let target = event.target;
  if (target.matches('button')) {
    let value = target.innerHTML

    let result = document.querySelector('#output').value += value

  }}

function operatorSign(e) {
    let operator = e.target;
    if (operator.matches('button')) {
      let value = operator.innerHTML

      if (value === "+") {
        return add(a, b)
      } else if (value === "-") {
        return subtract(a, b)
      } else if (value === "*") {
        return multiply(a, b)
      } else if (value === "/") {
          return divide(a, b)
      } else {
        return null
      }

    }
}
```

HTML for the selector:

```
<body>
      <button type="button" name="button" id="clear">Clear</button>
      <div id="buttons">
        <button type="button" name="button" id="button">1</button>
        <button type="button" name="button" id="button">2</button>
        <button type="button" name="button" id="button">3</button>
        <button type="button" name="button" id="button">4</button>
        <button type="button" name="button" id="button">5</button>
        <button type="button" name="button" id="button">6</button>
        <button type="button" name="button" id="button">7</button>
        <button type="button" name="button" id="button">8</button>
        <button type="button" name="button" id="button">9</button>
      </div>
      <div  id="operators">
        <button type="button" name="button" id="button">-</button>
        <button type="button" name="button" id="button">/</button>
        <button type="button" name="button" id="button">*</button>
        <button type="button" name="button" id="button">+</button>
        <button type="button" name="button" id="button">=</button>
      </div>
      <input type="text"  id="output">
      <script src="./script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Three things. First, global variables - which in this case just means in a simple html/js page how to reference the same variables in different functions. Just define a variable outside of the function scope and it will be available to other functions on that page

```
let myVal;
function thing() {
myVal = 5;
}

function otherThing(){
console.log(myVal); 
}

thing();
otherThing(); // shows in the console as 5
```

Second, your HTML needs some love. Setting everything with the same ID and the same name will cause problems for you. With this project, you don't actually need either of those because you're working from the actual button text (either a number or a math operator). So you can do away with all that.

```
<body>
  <button type="button" name="button" id="clear">Clear</button>
  <div id="buttons">
    <button type="button">1</button>
    <button type="button">2</button>
    <button type="button">3</button>
    <button type="button">4</button>
    <button type="button">5</button>
    <button type="button">6</button>
    <button type="button">7</button>
    <button type="button">8</button>
    <button type="button">9</button>
  </div>
  <div id="operators">
    <button type="button">-</button>
    <button type="button">/</button>
    <button type="button">*</button>
    <button type="button">+</button>
    <button type="button">=</button>
  </div>
  <input type="text"  id="output">
  <script src="./script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
```

Third, in your function, it's getting a number value from the input, but it's coming in as a string, and if you try to just add that to something, it will concatenate it instead. Convert it to a number:

```
function selector(event) {
  let target = event.target;
  if (target.matches('button')) {
    let value = target.innerHTML
    // any of these will work:
    // value = parseInt(value); // assuming there are no decimal points
    // value = +value
    // value = Number(value);

    // same goes for the other, so you can rewrite this like:

    let result = +document.querySelector('#output').value + +value
    // or
    // let result = Number(document.querySelector('#output').value) + Number(value)

  }}
```

```js
/* BEGIN SCRIPT.JS FILE */
var select = document.querySelector('#buttons')
var operating = document.querySelector('#operators')

select.addEventListener('click', selector)
operating.addEventListener('click', operatorSign)

let result;

function selector_OLD(event) {
  let target = event.target;
  if (target.matches('button')) {
    let value = target.innerHTML

    let result = document.querySelector('#output').value += value

  }
}

function selector(event) {
  let target = event.target;
  if (target.matches('button')) {
    let value = target.innerHTML
    // any of these will work:
    // value = parseInt(value); // assuming there are no decimal points
    // value = +value
    // value = Number(value);

    // same goes for the other, so you can rewrite this like:

    let result = +document.querySelector('#output').value + +value
    // or
    // let result = Number(document.querySelector('#output').value) + Number(value)

  }
}




function operatorSign(e) {
  let operator = e.target;
  if (operator.matches('button')) {
    let value = operator.innerHTML

    if (value === "+") {
      return add(a, b)
    } else if (value === "-") {
      return subtract(a, b)
    } else if (value === "*") {
      return multiply(a, b)
    } else if (value === "/") {
      return divide(a, b)
    } else {
      return null
    }

  }
}
/* END SCRIPT.JS FILE */
```

```html
<button type="button" name="button" id="clear">Clear</button>
<div id="buttons">
  <button type="button">1</button>
  <button type="button">2</button>
  <button type="button">3</button>
  <button type="button">4</button>
  <button type="button">5</button>
  <button type="button">6</button>
  <button type="button">7</button>
  <button type="button">8</button>
  <button type="button">9</button>
</div>
<div id="operators">
  <button type="button">-</button>
  <button type="button">/</button>
  <button type="button">*</button>
  <button type="button">+</button>
  <button type="button">=</button>
</div>
<input type="text" id="output">
```

Comment: this is getting me undefined. Can it be?

Comment: I can help you better if I see the script or HTML that is calling this `selector` function. Please add it to your question

Comment: Can you paste in the code from `./script.js` as well?

Comment: @AllenChen - I had a typo in my selector function which I updated ( the `+=` became just a `+`). I also ported all your code into a snippet and it runs without errors except it doesn't do anything yet. You're missing your `add()` etc operator functions. So when you get those added and you still have issues, send me a comment.